# updating and saving data in one button

Tags: vb.net

i want to have same command button for saving and updating data from vb.net to ms access...saving the data if it still doesn't exist and update if the data is already exist...can anyone help me please..here's my code for save command button and when i run it, the error shows like this, "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again."

```
Private Sub timer_save_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer_save.Tick

    If Not Me.strip_progress.Value = Me.strip_progress.Maximum Then
        Me.strip_progress.Increment(5)
        Me.strip_progress.Visible = True
    Else
        If Me.strip_progress.Value = Me.strip_progress.Maximum Then
            Me.timer_save.Stop()
            Me.strip_progress.Value = 0

            con.Open()

            If Me.txt_locid.Tag & "" = "" Then
                access = "Insert into tbl_location(locid, locname, locadd) Values ('" & txt_locid.Text & "', '" & txt_locname.Text & "', '" & txt_locadd.Text & "')"

                cmd = New OleDbCommand(access, con)
                cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                'con.Close()
                MsgBox("Successfully Saved....")

                Me.menu_update.Enabled = False
                Me.menu_save.Enabled = False

                Me.txt_locid.Enabled = False
                Me.txt_locname.Enabled = False
                Me.txt_locadd.Enabled = False

                Me.strip_progress.Visible = False
            Else
                access = "UPDATE tbl_location " & _
                         " SET locid=" & Me.txt_locid.Text & _
                         ", locname='" & Me.txt_locname.Text & "'" & _
                         ", locadd='" & Me.txt_locadd.Text & "'" & _
                         " WHERE locid=" & Me.txt_locid.Tag

                cmd = New OleDbCommand(access, con)
                cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                'con.Close()
                MsgBox("Successfully Updated...")

                Me.menu_update.Enabled = False
                Me.menu_save.Enabled = False

                Me.txt_locname.Enabled = False
                Me.txt_locadd.Enabled = False

            End If

        End If
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your database structure, one can only assume that your locid field is the primary key and you are trying to insert a value for it that already exists in the database.

Potentially you should leave that up to the database by allowing it to auto assign an identity value to the locid field (I believe it is called the autonumber type in MS Access) and then you can change your code to not insert or update that value. e.g.

```
            access = "Insert into tbl_location(locname, locadd) Values ('" & txt_locname.Text & "', '" & txt_locadd.Text & "')"
```

Comment: there's no problem regarding with my primary key..i think it's only in my if statement..that's why it shows error like that....at first, i create 2 different commands for saving and updating..and it run without error..but when i combined the code to use only one command button, that's the time i encountered the error...

Comment: The error you have shown suggests that you are attempting to add a record to your database with the same primary key value as one that is already in there - based on the code you have up there I can see why this would be so. It is quite unusual that you would be manually entering the primary key value from your form which is why I suggest removing that from your insert and update statements. There's nothing obviously wrong with your if statement although there are probably better ways to do it. With the information given I don't think I can suggest anything further.